# Unable to reference a Blazor Component Library project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, components, .net-standard, blazor

I am trying to follow this [article to create a razor component library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).
This in itself is not an issue.

The issue comes when i try to reference this project to my Blazor project.

When i create my Blazor project, it is always created as a .Net Standard project. The Razor component library is created as an Asp.net Core project.

I am unable to create the Blazor project as Asp.net Core.
And im unable to create the component library as .Net standard.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin here:

> I am unable to create the Blazor project as Asp.net Core

Selecting server-side Blazor results in a project in Asp.net Core
  With server-side Blazor you can create a Razor Class Library.
  With client-side Blazor you cannot create a Razor Class Library. You   can instead create a Blazor component library. 
The Blazor component library should be created by the blazorlib template in a command shell... Do this:

```
dotnet new blazorlib -o MyComponentLib1
```

Now add the newly created Blazor component library project to your solution, and use it according to the instructions described here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consume-a-library-component

Hope this helps...

Comment: So, I can't use Razor Class Library from Blazor Wasp? Can I use .NET standard library?

Comment: I'm certain that you know that blazorlib is obsolete and Razor Class Library is the way to go.